# Fancybox jquery problem in IE6

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using the 'Fancybox' jquery script to open some videos in a lightbox.

It's working fine in all browsers except for IE6.

The lightbox opens but then the video won't load.

Here's the link to the page -

http://www.bevelite.com.au/sky-glass-videos

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's how you're doing your videos, the 3rd video works for me in IE, but not the first two, and the 3rd you're doing the object tag and params different.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with IE today when using the latest jQuery 1.6, I simple downgraded to 1.4 the same as the example on [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) solving all the errors in IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```